# Position two images and make them look nice on mobile, the images does not have equal sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/183/)

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Two images that are not the same size should stay side by side in a full-width container and should keep the same height. (it works on my computer resolution = 1388px width), but at different resolutions the images won't have the same height.
2. On smaller resolution (for example less than 991px) the images will go one under another one (like it can be seen in the fiddle, but the issue here is that there is a space between images and the writing will not fit the second image height.
3. The last thing is: the writing in the second image (on desktop resolutions for example greater than 991px) should end exactly where the writing of the above paragraph ends. (the paragraph is in a bootstrap container)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid nopadding">
  <section id="about-us">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 nopadding">
      <div class="background-image-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2400x1600" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 nopadding">
      <div class="background-image-right" style="background:url('http://placehold.it/1920x481;') center center no-repeat">
        <div class="inner">
          <h2>About us</h2>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I need to keep these images at this size.

Answer (score 0):

You can add both images as background images. Also both of your div's having the background image need to have fixed equal height.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 nopadding">
        <div class="background-image-left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 nopadding">
        <div class="background-image-right">
            <div class="inner">
                <h2>About us</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.background-image-left, .background-image-right {
    height: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.background-image-left {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/2400x1600');
}
.background-image-right {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x481');
}
```